# Why do I keep getting error while opening eclipse juno in the first time?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-juno, logfile

I have download adt bundles with eclipse Juno inside, but when I extracted it keeps getting an error "an error has occurred, see the log file" please help me to solve this.

The log file :

> !SESSION 2021-05-25 10:58:01.885
> ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200 java.version=15 java.vendor=Oracle
> Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32,
> NL=en_ID Framework arguments:  -product
> com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct Command-line arguments:
> -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 4 0 2021-05-25
> 10:58:03.175 !MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR !STACK 0
> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle
> "org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.v20120914-163612 [1]"
> could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint:
> Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1,J2SE-1.4
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
> at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-05-25 10:58:03.183 !MESSAGE Bundle
> initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.v20120914-163612.jar
> was not resolved.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2021-05-25 10:58:03.201 !MESSAGE One or
> more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints
> are not resolved: !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2021-05-25
> 10:58:03.201 !MESSAGE Bundle
> initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.v20120914-163612.jar
> was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 2
> 0 2021-05-25 10:58:03.201 !MESSAGE Missing required capability
> Require-Capability: osgi.ee;
> filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.1))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4)))".
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2021-05-25 10:58:03.209 !MESSAGE The
> following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see
> the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists: !SUBENTRY 1
> org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2021-05-25 10:58:03.209 !MESSAGE Bundle
> org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.v20120914-163612 [1]
> was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 2
> 0 2021-05-25 10:58:03.209 !MESSAGE Missing required capability
> Require-Capability: osgi.ee;
> filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.1))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4)))".
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-05-25 10:58:03.222 !MESSAGE
> Application error !STACK 1 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to
> acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime
> bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).  at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)  at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)     at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)     at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

Comment: Juno was released in 2012. It is version 4.2. The latest Eclipse version is 4.19 and is referred to as Eclipse 2021-03. Note that the next version, 4.20, will be released next month, i.e. June 2021. You should download Eclipse from [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/)

Comment: Juno is far too old to run with anything after Java 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are using old version of Eclipse with new version of JDK. Please confirm the feasibility of eclipse with JDK.

To check the compatibility please refer:

[https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation#:~:text=to%20Install%20Eclipse.-,A%20Java%208%20or%20newer%20JRE%2FJDK%20is%20required%20to,as%20well%20as%20the%20Installer.](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation#:%7E:text=to%20Install%20Eclipse.-,A%20Java%208%20or%20newer%20JRE%2FJDK%20is%20required%20to,as%20well%20as%20the%20Installer.)

```
Eclipse Juno Compatible Version:  Pick either Java 6 or 7
```

Hope this will give you hint to proceed further.

Happy Coding!

Comment: This might help you. Compatibility of JDK with eclipse Juno. 
   https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=453618&goto=1009751&#msg_1009751